# Taskkill an untitled process?

Tags: java, batch-file, title, taskkill

So I'm using the taskkill.exe which comes with Vista and I want it to do something especially complicated..

There are multiple instances of java.exe running, and I want it to find the one that is untitled.. so this is my command:

```
taskkill /IM java.exe /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq "
```

I also tried:

```
taskkill /IM java.exe /FI "WINDOWTITLE ne AutoClicker"
```

It doesn't work anyways... So is there anyway... to target an untitled process???

Comment: Find the PID, then kill by pid.

Comment: @LatinSuD: You have the same problem; namely trying to filter for a window with no title – just then with `tasklist` instead of `taskkill`.

Comment: Sorry, I completely forgot that I cannot use tasklist because I am running this command on an automated program. It cannot parse PID's, and if it could, it wouldn't be able to tell it's PID from the one it has to end.

Answer (score 1):

You must first find the PID of the untitled process by parsing the results of TASKLIST, and then invoke TASKKILL with the found PID.

Try the following code

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('TASKLIST /V') do (
  set s=%%a
  set p=!s:~27,5!
  set t=!s:~152,3!
  if '!t!'=='N/A' ECHO TASKKILL /PID !p! /T
)
```

and after extra-careful testing, remove the ECHO